# Saving LocalDate to database

Tags: java, jpa

I am pretty new to this and have a couple of questions:

1. If i would need to record a date and time when user changed something in the UI, do i need to pass that date from the UI or is better for the back end to create a date and time object when the request reaches it?
2. If i would need to save LocalDate object to a database , would the following approach work?

   ```
    @Column(name = "last_preference_change_date")
    private LocalDateTime lastPreferenceChangeDate;
   ```

My goal is to record a moment when user changed particular settings and to store that in db to be able to retrieve it, and if that user for example reverted those changes i would like my existing date to be overwritten in db and new one saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PrePersist](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) and [PreUpdate](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html) callback/method to create function that can modify every data changed. It is applicable to any JPA provider.

```
@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
public void updateModified() {
    modifiedTime = new Date();
    if (createdTime == null) {
      createdTime = new Date();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below annotation for auditing

```
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

```
@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;
```

```
@LastModifiedBy
@CreatedBy
```